# How to make IE 9 or less work with this Multi Select In Pure JavaScript – vanillaSelectBox

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, multi-select

I found this multiselect https://www.cssscript.com/single-multi-select-vanilla/ and works with Chorme and IE10 but i need this to work with IE9 or less.
I followed all the steps of the pages and also tried this
chrome
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOK78.png)

IE
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhZ69.png)
// Polyfill Source

// BVSelect Polyfilled Version

because of this https://github.com/BMSVieira/BVSelect-VanillaJS#polyfill but it's not working or maybe do you know to build a multiselect box? compatible with IE9

Comment: IE9? Did my time machine actually work and it is 2011?

Comment: @epascarello so... that means. you know how to do it. Right?

Comment: I have not looked at IE9 in years since the browser support ended in 2017. Plus I doubt anyone is going to download a zip file, load up a VM and figure out why it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line code will fix the problem!:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
```